# How do you return an empty object in Typescript - or is there another way?

Tags: typescript, object

I'm learning Typescript (and React) and I'm trying to check if an object is null in order to skip further processing. I have a minimal example below.

If inputCat is null, I want to return right away to skip further processing, how do I do that in TypeScript?

```
  declare class Cat {
      color: string;
      // lots of more properties here
  }

  const processCat = (inputCat: Cat): Cat => {
      if(!inputCat) {
          return {};  // throws error: "Property 'color' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Cat'."
      }

      // lots of processing here
      return {
          ... inputCat,
          // lots of new variables here
      }
  }
```

When I try to return an empty object, TypeScript is complaining that:

> Property 'color' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Cat'.

How do I return empty objects or null in Typescript? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: According to your declaration, a Cat is *required* to have `color`. If it doesn't have it, it's not a `Cat`. If you really want an empty object to be a valid Cat, you either need to make all the properties optional (not recommended) or use a type assertion (also not recommended). This is more of a design problem, though - *why* return an empty object at all here? Also, since you have a class, you should be instantiating it. To that effect `declare class` does not make sense, since it doesn't actually make a real class, just an ambient one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `null` to return type (use union type `Cat | null`)

```
  const processCat = (inputCat: Cat): Cat | null => {
      if(!inputCat) {
          return null;
      }

      // lots of processing here
      return {
          ... inputCat,
          // lots of new variables here
      }
  }
```